# I want to show default address in checkout shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

I want to show a specific address in the shipping address every time whether a customer has a shipping address or not.

No matter cart is a guest or logged in only a specific address should show in the checkout shipping address.

I don't want to allow customers or anyone to edit or update that address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this template to set the default shipping address.

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html**

Find out the template and modify it like this

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="CSS: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <div>
        <span>Street: </span>
        <span>Your Specific Street</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>City: </span>
        <span>Your Specific City</span>
    </div>
</div>
```